# Retrieving data from span with jquery and c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to retrieve some values from span which are inside a td. I have this function:

```
function reorder() {
    alert("Entrando en reorder");
    strorder = "";
    var totalid = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados tr td input').length;
    alert(totalid);
    for (var i = 0; i < totalid; i++) {
      strorder = strorder +$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados tr td span')[i].text()+"*"+ $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados tr td input')[i].getAttribute("value") + "|";
      alert("strorder1"); 
    }
    //strorder = window.location.href;
    alert("strorder2");
}
```

And the source code is this (a piece of the code):

```
<table class="table table-hover tablaDimensiones" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">
      <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados&#39;,&#39;Sort$titulo&#39;)">Título</a>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_lblTitulo">Dimension1</span>
      <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$hdnid" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_hdnid" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_cmdEditar" title="Editar" class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$cmdEditar&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      &nbsp;
      <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;¿Desea elimnar la dimensión?&#39;);" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_cmdEliminar" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$cmdEliminar&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

How can I do it?, because in this way I don't have what I want. Regards

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to retrieve? And are you wanting to retrieve it on the client side or server side?

Comment: I'm trying to get the span texts, on the code behind, they are labels but on the client side are span so I want to retrieve the span text to concate to the other values.

Comment: on the client side always

Comment: will the spans always have that particular ID, you can pick it up by that? or are you after the contents of all the spans on the page?

Comment: spans can change the id, I mean ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_lblTitulo and the next one ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl03_lblTitulo and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive that the following example is what you looking for you've almost correct code you should just organize it a little.

**NOTE :** The only error in your code is in the long line :

```
strorder = strorder +$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados tr td span')[i].text()+"*"+ $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados tr td input')[i].getAttribute("value") + "|";
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function reorder() {
  var strorder = "";
  var table_spans = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados span[id^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1"]');
  var table_inputs = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados input');

  for (var i = 0; i < table_inputs.length; i++) 
  {
    var span_text = table_spans.eq(i).text();
    var input_value = table_inputs.eq(i).val();

    strorder +=  span_text + "*" + input_value + "|";
  }
  
  console.log(strorder);
}

reorder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover tablaDimensiones" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">
      <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados&#39;,&#39;Sort$titulo&#39;)">Título</a>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_lblTitulo">Dimension1</span>
      <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$hdnid" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_hdnid" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_cmdEditar" title="Editar" class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$cmdEditar&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      &nbsp;
      <a onclick="return confirm(&#39;¿Desea elimnar la dimensión?&#39;);" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_cmdEliminar" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResultados$ctl02$cmdEliminar&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Bad practice querying DOM in loop

Comment: How could I get the span with id which have a pattern?, if you can see I just want span which have the id like ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados_ctl02_lblTitulo and so on, no this one: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>

Comment: You could add start-with selector `^` check my update... selector will be `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResultados span[id^="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1"]')`.. (If the answer helps you vote  it up)

Answer (score 0):

This code gets every text inside every span in your table td.

```
var strorder = "";
var spans=$("table.table").find("td").find("span");
var inputs=$("table.table").find("td").find("input");

for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
   strorder+=$(spans[i]).text()+"*"+$(inputs[i]).val()+"|";
}
```

Or without second array:

```
var strorder = "";
var spans=$("table.table").find("td").find("span");

for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
   var $span=$(spans[i]); //temporary jquery object
   strorder+=$span.text()+"*"+$span.next().val()+"|"; //$span.next() ==input
}
```

**PS.** saving `array.length` to  **totalid** is not required because length is property not method, so getting length in loop is optimal solution.

Comment: And row by row how do you that?.

Comment: I changed from text() to val() on inputs, text() for inputs will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be optimistic

```
 $td = $('.tablaDimensiones tr td');

        var spans = $td.find('span');
        var inps = $td.find('input');

        var len = spans.length;

        var sortorder = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sortorder += spans.eq(i).text() + "*" + inps.eq(i).text() + "|";             
        }
```